# Escaping special XML characters in strings

Tags: java, string

I am creating an input xml to database procedure which i am creating manually through

```
StringBuilder.append();
```

finally when all my xml is created i am converting StringBuilder to string by

```
stringBuilder.tostring()
```

now the problem is i am getting &(ampersand) in string which i am  giving input to oracle\n
stored procedure i have also replaced ampersand by

```
stringUtils.remove(string,'&')
```

but still oracle stored procedure is giving error for & (ampersand)

i want ask that is any character is getting converted to "ampersand character" in my string
like

```
&cent; &gt; &lt; &quot; &divide;
```

Comment: _Don't build XML by hand_; you'll just get problems like this one.  Instead, use an XML library.

Comment: yes friend its correct but if use xstream or other framework it will convert character like " ' " to ampersand character i donot want & or any type of ampersand character

Comment: This problem is completely unrelated to class `StringBuilder` or converting from it to `String`. Please retitle your question accordingly. Suggestion: it's related to escaping `&` in Strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't really be building XML by hand at all - it's error prone and pretty much reinventing the wheel. For ongoing development I'd seriously consider a dedicated XML library.

However, if you want to quickly escape such characters look to the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library:

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml("Here is data & containing special <chars>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include all of XML's special characters ('&','<','>',''','"') in XPL. The XPL to XML conversion utilities will handle everything for you. http://hll.nu